# Adding custom page to PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdfbox

I have an application that I have used in the past that used PD4ML to generate PDFs from a template and then I would use PDFBox to add a custom page at the end of the PDF that contains a rather large image.

So I would have 20 or so Portrait pages at A4 and then 2 pages at the end that were custom sized based on the image (sometimes 2000x2000).

Now I'm working an a very similar process with PHP and the one issue I am seeing at the moment is adding those custom pages. I'm using Smarty and DOMPDF to template/create PDF. But I don't see anything that indicates Smarty can use custom pages.

Is there a library out there that can be used in a similar manner? Add a PDF page that has (x) width and (y) height and then allow for re-rendering?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out "TCPDF" and lots of templates here: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

try this code:

```
$pdf = new CUSTOMPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8',     false);  
//Add a custom size  
$width = 175;  
$height = 266;
```

Comment: Having looked this up, couple things to note: 1) I have large HTML input into the tool, which doesn't appear to work at all for some reason. 2) I can't actually load an existing PDF file to add a page to it.